# how to make pie chart using non-contiguous data in openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I am trying to create a pie chart using openpyxl. The problem is that I need to use non-contiguous cells to populate the pie chart. I can't seem to figure out how to do it.

**Attempt 1**

```
chart2=PieChart()
data1=Reference(range_string='mysheet!E%s,mysheet!G%s' % (row_count,row_count))
chart2.add_data(data1)
chart2.dataLabels = DataLabelList()
chart2.dataLabels.showVal = True
chart2.width=35
sheet14.add_chart(chart2,"A16")
wb.save('h:\\desktop\\example_copy.xlsx')
```

Results in a pie chart where data has range 'mysheet!E5,mysheet'!$G$5. Note that this makes excel believe that I am trying to pull data from a single cell from a sheet titled "mysheet!E5,mysheet"

**Attempt 2**

Same code except that I have replaced the 2nd and 3rd lines with the following code:

```
data1=Reference(range_string='mysheet!E%s' % row_count)
data2=Reference(range_string='mysheet!G%s' % row_count)
chart2.add_data(data1)
chart2.add_data(data2)
```

This seems to work at getting the data into the graph, but to display correctly I need to go and switch the row and columns on the graph. But since it needs to be automated this isn't going to work.

How can I populate this pie chart with my data correctly?

Comment: I'm not sure I entirely understand what you need to do. What you seem to be doing doesn't quite seem to match the question. openpyxl will happily transpose rows and columns but does expect to work with contiguous data. You may have to reverse engineer an existing chart.

Comment: It's not so much that I need to transpose the rows and columns. Rather I have two non-contiguous data points that I have to turn into a pie chart. I also can't just rewrite the format of the data, that is fixed and must continue to be in its current format. In the second attempt the chart displays but it displays only 1 of the numbers. If I open the chart and transpose the rows and columns it displays correctly.

Comment: There is probably some way to get it to work in OpenPyXL, but I rarely use that package, and I never use charts. However, I do use XlsxWriter a lot, so I gave that a try, and I was able to get discontinuous "series" to work, in what is the obvious way for XlsxWriter (basically your first attempt). It emits a couple of warnings about screwy references, but faithfully uses the disjoint range segments anyway, and the resulting chart looks right.

Comment: Yeah its been over 24 hours and I still can't seem to figure this one out. I'm starting to wonder if doing this in OpenPyXL is the right choice. I'm about to jump ship and XlsxWriter looks like it might have to be my solution.